# Add iPhone XR support to existing iOS app in Xcode 10

Tags: autolayout, ios11, xcode10, iphone-x

I have an `iOS` application that is working fine in an `iPhone X or XR` the only problem is that i see the black areas on top and bottom so the app is not taking the hole of the screen.

Im using `Auto Layout` option in the Storyboard.

I also was reading that you can fix this by adding a Launch Image specific size to the assets but I just opened my assets and I don't see a new space for iPhone X or XR images.

[image]

Im I doing something wrong?

Comment: try remove and add again AppIcon assets

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a LaunchScreen.storyboard with a ImageView you need to uncheck "Use Safe Area Layout Guides" or set Up and Bottom constraints to superview instead of Safe Area.